# Copy rows from one table to another without creating duplicates

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel workbook that has a master sheet that keeps track of items and their current location, and another sheet that keeps track of past locations or where an item has been. Currently when a record is changed in the master sheet, the row is manually copied and pasted into the 2nd sheet. I would like to create a macro that would find items in the master sheet that are not in the 2nd sheet and copy them to the 2nd sheet when records change.

Below is a sample macro I found and modified that is close, but it copies and pastes *all* rows instead of the new or different ones. The rows would only need to be compared on columns A, B, and D.

```
Public Sub Sample()
Dim shM As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
Dim shMData As Variant
Dim sh2DataA As Variant
Dim sh2Data As Variant
Dim iM As Long, os2 As Long, i2 As Variant
Dim DoSearch As Boolean

Set shM = Sheets(1)
Set sh2 = Sheets(2)

With shM
    shMData = .Range(.[A1], .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 4)
End With

DoSearch = False
For iM = 2 To UBound(shMData, 1)
    With sh2
        sh2DataA = .Range(.[A1], .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 1)
        sh2Data = .Range(.[A1], .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 4)
    End With
    os2 = 0
    Do
        If UBound(shMData, 1) > 1 Then
            i2 = Application.Match(shMData(iM, 1), sh2DataA, 0)

        Else
            If shMData(iM, 1) = sh2DataA Then
                i2 = 1
            Else
                i2 = CVErr(xlErrNA)
            End If

        End If

        If Not IsError(i2) Then

                If (shMData(iM, 2) = sh2Data(i2, 2)) And (shMData(iM, 4) = sh2Data(i2, 4)) Then
                MsgBox "Match found Master = " & iM & ", sheet2 = " & i2 + os2

                Else

                    shM.Activate
                    shM.Range(Cells(iM, 1), Cells(iM, 7)).Select
                    Selection.Copy

                    sh2.Select
                    FinalRow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
                    NextRow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    Range("A" & NextRow).Select
                    ActiveSheet.Paste

                End If


            os2 = os2 + i2
            If os2 < UBound(sh2Data, 1) Then
                With sh2
                    sh2DataA = .Range(.Cells(i2 + os2, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 1)
                    sh2Data = .Range(.Cells(i2 + os2, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 4)
                End With
                DoSearch = True

            Else
                DoSearch = False
            End If

        Else
            shM.Activate
            shM.Range(Cells(iM, 1), Cells(iM, 7)).Select
            Selection.Copy

            sh2.Select
            FinalRow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
            NextRow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            Range("A" & NextRow).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste

            DoSearch = False
        End If
    Loop Until Not DoSearch
Next
End Sub
```

The message box was added only to verify that the code was working - it is not a necessary component.  Thanks again for any advice you can give.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you never get two rows of the exact same thing in your master list, you can just use the built-in Excel feature Remove Duplicates (on the Data tab in 2010 at least).  If you have x duplicate rows, all the same, x-1 of them are deleted.  So, you could just copy the entire other table, paste it below the master list, and then run remove duplicates on the master list.  All you need to know is the VBA for removing duplicates.

```
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$40:$D$43").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 3, 4), Header:=xlNo
```

Adjust as necessary

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help I found a solution however it does not work in Excel 2003.  If anyone knows off the top of their head why that would be great else I think I figure it out.  Here is the code.

[HTML]Public Sub NewEntWhole()
    Dim loM As ListObject, lo2 As ListObject
    Dim TblMData As Variant
    Dim iM As Long
    Dim dDate As Date
    Dim strDate As String
    Dim lDate As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim ct As Variant
    Dim shM As Worksheet
    Dim sh2 As Worksheet
    Dim hdM As Integer

```
hdM = 0 'rows above table M
Set shM = Sheets(1)
Set sh2 = Sheets(2)
Set loM = Sheets(1).ListObjects(1)
Set lo2 = Sheets(2).ListObjects(1)



With loM
    TblMData = .DataBodyRange
End With

For iM = 2 To UBound(TblMData, 1) + 1
    sh2.Activate


    With lo2
        .Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=loM.Range(iM, 1).Value
        .Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=loM.Range(iM, 2).Value

        If IsDate(loM.Range(iM, 4)) Then
            sDate = loM.Range(iM, 4)
            dDate = DateSerial(Year(sDate), Month(sDate), Day(sDate))
            lDate = dDate
            .Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=">=" & lDate, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<" & lDate + 1
        Else
            .Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=loM.Range(iM, 4).Value
        End If


    End With

   Set rng = lo2.AutoFilter.Range

    ct = rng.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count - 1

    If ct = 0 And loM.Range(iM, 1).Value > 0 Then

        shM.Activate
        shM.Range(Cells((iM + hdM), 1), Cells((iM + hdM), 7)).Copy

        sh2.Activate
        FinalRow = Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row
        NextRow = Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Range("A" & NextRow).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste

    End If

    With lo2
        .Range.AutoFilter Field:=1
        .Range.AutoFilter Field:=2
        .Range.AutoFilter Field:=4
    End With
Next
shM.Activate
```

End Sub[/HTML]